# Checking a list to make a decision

Tags: python, python-2.7

all.

I'm trying to write a script that checks the age of some files in a folder, and deletes the old files if new files have been created. If new files were not created, then it does not delete the old files and it sends me an email telling me that no new files were created.

I use the OS module ctime to check the age of files, and I'm using an external script "sendmail" to handle the emailing.

As it works now, it correctly determines old and new files, and then deletes old files, but it does not correctly make the decision about whether or not to call sendmail. Let me show you:

```
for fn in os.listdir(path, f)
 fn = os.path.jion(path, f)
 ctime = os.stat(fn).st_ctime
 if ctime > now - 1 * 86400: #this is a new file
  new_files.append(fn)
  countit = new_files.count(fn) #counting the occurence of appended files
 if new_Files.count(fn) > countit: #checks the list
  import sendmail
   sendmail
 elif ctime < now - 10 * 86400: #checking for old file
  old_files.append(fn)
if new_files:
 for fn in old_files:
  os.remove(fn)
```

So, can I get some help on this? I'm really stuck. Should I be using an `elif` statement to check my list, like so:

```
if ctime > now - 1 * 86400:
 new_files.append(fn)
elif:
 import sendmail
  sendmail
```

Is that a proper way to write that? Is there a correct way to write this decision? Is my whole script wrong?

EDIT - Sorry if I'm being whiny, I've been working on this for some time, and it's very frustrating. I appreciate whatever help you can give!!!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you think ``elif`` does - it's short for else if, and is used after an if statement to perform another check. If you want it to be run in all cases, you want ``else``.

Comment: The indentation is confusing - are you trying to send a separate email for every filename?  I'd assume you'd want a single email at the end - `if new_files: remove old files else: sendmail`

Comment: Do you mean to have both a `new_Files` variable and a `new_files` variable?

Comment: Your second line probably doesn't do what you want it to do. `fn = os.path.join(path, f)` will cause every iteration of your loop to do exactly the same thing. Did you mean `fn = os.path.join(path, fn)`? (I also assumed you meant `os.path.join()` and not `os.path.jion()`)

Comment: Yes, assume typos. I only use the new_files variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you probably want to do something like this:

```
for fn in os.listdir(path, f):
    fn = os.path.join(path, f)
    ctime = os.stat(fn).st_ctime
    if ctime > now - 1 * 86400: #this is a new file
        new_files.append(fn)
        countit = new_files.count(fn) #counting the occurrence of appended files
    elif ctime < now - 10 * 86400: #checking for old file
        old_files.append(fn)
if new_files:
    for fn in old_files:
        os.remove(fn)
else:
    import sendmail
        sendmail.sendmail()
```

Comment: Like the OP, you are missing a `:` in the first line. I'm also pretty sure that the last line is a function call `()`.

Comment: @Hooked Yeah, I ignored the `sendmail` part making no sense as I assumed it was a placeholder for what the OP was actually doing, which may not be the case. I will update it to be more syntactically correct.

Comment: Holy long string of expletives. Regardless, I'd say for my first time actually using Python this is going incredibly well.

I'll give this a shot, but I'm pretty sure it's the answer I've been looking for.

Me and my brain. This is my brain on Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble determining what exactly sendmail is doing/what its supposed to do.  Could you post that module as well?

Also, I would recommend putting the import statement at the top of the file, so that you don't have to import the file multiple times.  This should speed up performance significantly.

Also, I'm having trouble understanding what the line "os.listdir(path, f)" is doing.  Whenever I try the method os.listdir with more than 1 argument, I get an error.  Is this a typo?

Comment: Sendmail just uses SMTP to send me an email at my personal, for testing purposes. What's more important is that the sendmail script works by itself, it's calling it that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I use the OS module ctime to check the age of files...

Whoops! ctime isn't when the file was created on all operating systems; do *not* rely on it unless you are certain which OS you are on. mtime is the last modification time instead, but is supported on all operating systems.

Comment: It's supported on Windows, I'm going to be use the file on a Windows server. I thought about modified time, but what if we went in and viewed the file or did a restore from it, or some process touched it, the mtime would change and the script could be evaluated wrong.